# How to migrate JAAS- J2C authentication data from Websphere to Liberty

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I am trying to migrate a web application from Websphere 8.5.5 to Liberty 16.0.0.3. Within Websphere i used to have defined some J2C security entries which i then loaded programatically. How can i achieve this in Liberty?

I tried defining an "authData" entry in server.xml and then load it through AuthDataProvider.getAuthData() but this requires "passwordUtilities-1.0" feature which if activated messes up my application because whenever i try to access the application through the browser an authorization pop-up is displayed.

Can anyone explain me how can i fix this or if i should do it in a different way? Any hint would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have security constraints defined that are protecting the web application - either in web.xml or annotations? Is this the same app that does not prompt you in WebSphere 8.5.5?

If there are security constraints defined in the app it will be prompted since passwordUtilities-1.0 includes the appSecurity feature. If the app has security constraints and cannot be removed for some reason, you can assign the EVERYONE special subject to the your application roles using the application-bnd element of the application to avoid prompting. An example:

```
<application location="myApp.war">
 <application-bnd>
     <security-role name="appRoleName"> <!-- role name listed in the security constraints -->
         <special-subject type="EVERYONE"/>
     </security-role>
 </application-bnd>
</application>
```